# Understanding softmax layer in Deep Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

In a DNN, once the logits vector is produced say

$[y_0,y_1]$ where the number of neuron in the logits layer is 2, the condition holds where $y_0 >= 0$ and $y_1<= 1$.

This vector is then passed into the softmax layer where it squeezes the value to be within the range of 0 to 1. However, how do i **prove that $y_0$ will always be $>=0$ and $y_1$ will always be $<=1$?**

From the way i understand, both $y_0 + y_1 = 1$ hence $y_0 >= 0$ and $y_1 <=1$ but i find that it doesn't really prove on why $y_0 >= 0$ and $y_1 <=1$. Could anyone assist me on my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Look at the definition of softmax:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function

[image]

The exp() gives a positive value. Since you "standardize" each value exp(e^z) in the numerator by the sum of all exp(e^z), the values sum to one in total.

Is whis what you are looking for?

Maybe you should have a look at Hasties et al. "Elements of Statistical Learning" (Ch. 11.2 "Neural Nets").

**Little R example:**

```
# For standardization (denominator)
base = exp(-2) + exp(5) 

# Single exp() values are positive
exp(-2)
[1] 0.1353353
exp(5)
[1] 148.4132

# Standatdize
exp(-2)/base 
[1] 0.0009110512
exp(5)/base 
[1] 0.9990889

# Total sum equals 1
exp(-2)/base + exp(5)/base 
[1] 1
```

Comment: thank you. So instead of negative, if i provide a value more than 1, say exp(5) /base the value would be standardized to {0,1}? So the exp() handles values that are negative and positive, squeezing their range to be between 0 and 1?

Comment: 1) The exponential function exp() makes values z "non-negative". 2) Dividing each single exp(z) by the sum of all exp(z) ensures that the exp(z) in total equals one. Consequently, a single sigma(z) must be >=0 and <= 1. If you feel that this helped you, a vote is apprechiated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Comment: thank you so much. Appreciated it. Fully understood! Cheers